# Multiple media queries for the same break point

Tags: css

I've received some template for mobile nav from an agency and saw that they have different media queries for the same breakpoint (991px in this case) like below, one after the other. Normally, I only code using the 3rd option, which is only specifying max-width without orientation. Is there any point in doing things like this, **especially when I compared side by side and noticed there's almost no difference between their 1st and 2nd media query**. Should I just dedupe then combine all 3?

```
@media (max-width:991px) and (orientation:portrait) {}
@media (max-width:991px) and (orientation:landscape) {}
@media (max-width:991px) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are safe to take out the portrait and landscape options as they are overridden by the 3rd option.

However, the very fact that the question was asked and that we are pondering this means that it is not completely intuitive. If you think about the more ‘normal’ CSS rules a more specific rule overrides a less specific one. For example

```
p.col { color: red; }
p { color: green; }
```

Paragraphs with class col will have text in red.

By contrast

```
@media (orientation : portrait), @media ( orientation : landscape ) {
  p { color: red; }
}

p { color: green; }
```

Will have paragraphs in green even though a more specific selection has been made beforehand.

It might be clearer for future readers of the code therefore to keep the portrait and landscape media queries and ditch the general (the 3rd) one, especially if there are quite a few instances of portrait or landscape media queries as this would clearly show where they are the same.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to combine the code because there's no difference in the code between the portrait and landscape orientation - just duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

@Kelly, It seems that, it may change only for tablets, phones and for devices which may have portrait and landscape features. Think about you change your devices main axis, eg. horizontol to vertical. Then this CSS code come to the scene. I think you should apply the current media query, if you want your views be responsive for that kind of situations.

Comment: Remember  that CSS orientation does not tell you the orientation of the device but of the viewport. On a windows PC the browser may be operating on a window which is in portrait mode. On something like an iPhone, although the device may be being held in portrait orientation the viewport can become landscape if the keyboard appears for example.